# Advice on uploading trading bot .exe files to a VPS to run 24/7

Tags: python, c++, bots, web-hosting, algorithmic-trading

I've made a trading bot that uses a c++ .exe for the backend (compute the predictions) and a python .exe for the the frontend (UI, placing trades, keeping track of trades, fetching market data, etc..). Currently I'm running it simply on my laptop, the backend only uses ~1mb process memory at any point, while the frontend uses ~72mb at any point. (The Python memory is calculated using this code:

```
import os, psutil
while Process_is_running:
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print(process.memory_info().rss)
```

)

I have never worked with web based applications (besides the python-binance api I guess) or any VPS type service. I am a self taught programmer of only 7 months, roughly.
I just want a basic nudge in the right direction, hopefully somewhere I can read up on the best way to do this.
The details of the program are as follows:

The Frontend automatically logs in to Binance, of course if it runs 24/7 this will only happens once, but if something goes wrong and it has to restart it would log in by itself, though I dont mind receiving a webhook notification or something of the sort to notify me of an event like this so I can log in manually.

The frontend simply sends "commands" and market data to the backend and then the backend simply sends the prediction back and current state of the algorithm. (ie.. "is predicting", "on stand by", "is training")

the reason for doing this is that my location has very unreliable power supply and not very good internet, so it often has to reboot and if it stays offline for too long, of course I might loose money or the program might lose track of the latest trades.

So in Summary: Can anyone just point me in the right direction where I can look for information on this topic, specifically related to my situation? Normally I would spend the time myself, but I am on a massive time constraint here so any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also implementing a bot. So cool that you are doing so as well. I think that it's really the way to go, making emotionless, data-driven trades.

Anyways, if I were you, I would start an AWS instance. Either Linux or Windows.

If you can run your software on Linux, that would be cheaper, as you won't have to pay the (somewhat small) overhead of Windows licensing.

Windows instances are fine, though. Here are the docs on getting started with [AWS windows instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html).

I know that you're just getting started, and you probably have multiple things that you want to do with this project. One suggestion for a direction that you could take is to go serverless. Of course there will be some server, but AWS can abstract that away from you to where you. This can make it both cheaper to run your bot and simpler to manage.

Comment: much appreciated friend! this is exactly what I was looking for :) Happy auto-trading!

Comment: One more thing is that, since you're using the network, you will need to configure the security group for the instance to allow inbound and outbound traffic to/from the IP/port that you need.